# What is the etymology of чашка? Какова этимология слова "чашка"?

Tags: этимология, история-языка

*Does it have anything in common with Sanskrit चषक (casaaka) = bowl, glass, cup, wine, liquour? Please avoid elliptic definitions like 'it is a diminutive from 'чаша'.*

Есть ли у слова что-либо общее с санскритским चषक (casaaka) = "кубок, стакан, чашка, вино, сладкий винный напиток"? Пожалуйста, избегайте эллиптических определений наподобие "это уменьшительное от слова "чаша".

Answer (score 2):

I am inclined to think there is no etymological connection between the Russian and Sanskrit words.

The [dictionary](http://glossword.info/index.php/term/,6ea3ab6f59585e926e6b6a9a5aa4a459955b71a460a6a9545b575aa5589aa2565958989a61a69f5e6e939fa1b05c5cacaab198aa5dac9a5761.xhtml) says about Russian `чаша`: "Более предпочтительным кажется толкование *kesja > чаша как суф. образования от *кесати > чесать в значении "чесать, отделять, резать, долбить". В таком случае чаша буквально — "деревянная выдолбленная или вырезанная посуда".

But the Sanskrit `cashaka` is apparently connected with the Sanskrit verbal root `cash` - "to eat."

Comment: Well, what about Russian кушать?...

Comment: @Manjusri, it doesn't have anything to do with eating/drinking. When in doubt, turn to Vasmer (http://vasmer.narod.ru/p345.htm). "Кушать" comes from old-slavic въкоушати, "to try".

Comment: Поскольку во всех производных от этого слова есть корень куш/кус, то логично предположить санскритскую первооснову (на альвеолярное ш).

Comment: @Manjusri, в крайнем случае можно предполагать праиндоевропейскую первооснову в чём бы то ни было, а логично предполагая санскритскую первооснову.

Comment: @Manjusri - Во-первых, корень слова "кушать" не чередуется с "кус", а слова "кусать" и "кусок" не связано с "кушать". Во-вторых, с чего вы взяли, что русское "к" соответствует санскритскому "ч"? С чего вы взяли, что русское "ш" соответствует санскритскому альвеолярному "ш"? И да, shabunc прав, русский от санскрита не произошёл.

Comment: Во-первых, никакого "предположения санскритской первоосновы" или юмористического "русского, произошедшего от санскрита" в моих комментариях нет. Во-вторых, с чего кто-то считает, будто латинское С читается в транслитерации санскритских слов как К? Оно читается как Ч. В-третьих, есть слова "искушать" и "искусить", которые по столь популярному у местной публики Фасмеру восходят к одной древнерусской первооснове. И - да! - слова "покушаться" Фасмер трактовал так же.

Comment: @Manjusri - К чему тогда вы писали про "санскритскую первооснову"? Я спрашивал о "русское "к" соответствует санскритскому "ч", потому что, как я понял, вы связываете "корень куш/кус" со словом "cashaka" или глаголом "cash". "Соответствует" ведь не значит "читается", я говорю о фонологических компаративистских соответствиях между родственными языками.

Comment: @Manjusri - Извините за оффтопик, но не могли бы вы сказать, по каким книгам вы собираетесь тангутский учить? Они есть у вас в электронном виде? Мы могли бы обменяться, у меня есть отсканированный словарь Ли Фаньвеня, и я заканчиваю сканировать [эту](http://www.orientalstudies.ru/rus/index.php?option=com_publications&Itemid=75&pub=519) книгу. Если что, пишите мне на hexenhammer2000-a собака yahoo.co.uk (и без пробелов).